# rails + backbone reports that confirmation field in model is empty upon creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, backbone.js, model

I'm creating a user model via backbone. password field has a confirmation field. if i create a user via a console - it's  created. but if i try to create a model via backbone it's an error - "Password_confirmation can't be blank".
I've looked for typo or any other simple error for quite a wile... Here is my code
view:

```
class Notes.Views.signupView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['users/signup']
  events:
    'submit form#create_user': 'createUser'
  checkField: (fieldId) ->
    $('#'+fieldId).val() != ''

  inputFilled: ->
    @checkField( 'name' ) && @checkField( 'email' ) && @checkField( 'password' ) && $('#password').val() == $('#password_confirmation').val()
  readAttributes: ->
    atr =
      name: $('#name').val()
      email: $('#email').val()
      password: $('#password').val()
      password_confirmation: $('#password_confirmation').val()

  createUser: (e)->
    e.preventDefault()
    unless @inputFilled()
      alert 'All fields must be filled, passwords must match'
      return
    attributes = @readAttributes()
    @model = new Notes.Models.User(attributes)
    @model.save attributes,
      wait: true
      success: -> alert('OK')
      error: @handleError
  handleError: (entry,response) ->
    if response.status == 422
      errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors
      for attribute, messages of errors
        alert "#{attribute} #{message} " for message in messages
  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    this
```

console shows that a request is send with these params:

```
{"name":"elmor","email":"elmorelmor@ukr.net","password":"elmor","password_confirmation":"elmor"}
```

response to it

```
{"errors":{"password_confirmation":["can't be blank"]}}
```

And my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_protected :password_digest
  attr_accessible :password, :facebook, :linkedin, :name, :email,  :twitter, :web
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, email: true
  validates :password, presence: true, :confirmation => true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: { if: :password }

  def password=(pass)
    return if pass.blank?
    @password = pass
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(pass)
  end
end
```

**Update 1**
if i insert `:password_confirmation` into `attr_accessible` i get 500 error as a response, but new user is created! i don't think that suppressing this error is the right think to do, so hoping to find a better way...

**Update 2**
Forgot to add controller's code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    respond_with User.create(params[:user])
  end

end
```

Update 3
I think i found root of this error - on production.log i can see an error, when i submit this form

```
Processing by UsersController#create as JSON

      Parameters: {"name"=>"elmor", "email"=>"elmor@ukr.net", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "name"=>"elmor", "email"=>"elmor@ukr.net"}}
```

`password_confirmation`  doesn't exists inside `user`... and i don't know why - take a look into backbone view... it's all there ^(
And a model -

```
class Notes.Models.User extends Backbone.Model
  url: '/api/account'
  # paramRoot: 'user' i tried with or without this line... Still error with
```

Comment: It's a virtual attribute. set by `:confirmation => true`

Comment: Which gem? backbone-on-rails? yes

Comment: I think `paramRoot` comes from [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) not [backbone-on-rails](https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails).

Comment: Found answer. posted it for anyone who runs into the same problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I've added location attribute to action in controller

```
  def create
    respond_with User.create(params[:user]),:location => signup_path
  end
```

and added `:password_confirmation` to `attr_accessible` in the model. and that's it!